# Duplicating reputation gain entries for the same event in my profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-history

I saw my [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2794409/han?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2018-09-07%2022:43:47Z) in my profile after someone upvote my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230321/2794409). The answer had 3 votes before, so I saw something like this.

[image]

Then I click the arrow button in the +30 line. It shows 4 +10 lines. Is this behaviour normal? I thought it should be 3 rows because the 4th one appears at the row above the +30 line.

[image]

This behaviour is produceable by clicking this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2794409/han?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2018-09-07%2022:43:47Z).

Comment: I've been seeing this for years, I just never thought anything of it.

Comment: This is a long-standing issue that has been known for years: [Expanding an event group shows more events than labeled when there are new events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139091/expanding-an-event-group-shows-more-events-than-labeled-when-there-are-new-event)